# error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Tags: c#, object, datatable

My code:

```
foreach(var row in dt_test.Rows)
{
    if (DateTime.ParseExact(row["TestDate"].ToString(),"dd.MM.yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) > DateTime.ParseExact("01.11.2019","dd.MM.yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        dt_test.Rows.Remove(row);
    }
}
dt_test.AcceptChanges();
```

Error:

> error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

How i can fix it?

I tried to redo for linq query, but nothing worked out for me.

Comment: Apart from the error, you cannot remove rows from a DataTable while you're enumerating it. Fill a remove-list and remove them afterwards.

Comment: change `var` to `DataRow`

Comment: In your foreach loop, replace `var` with `DataRow`. (The collection type for the rows is a non-generic collection, with its enumerator providing the collection items only typed as object. Which the `var` keyword then assumes as exactly that type for the `row` variable, hence the error when trying to use an indexer on a reference/variable of type object.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that you use `var` in the `foreach` and not `DataRow`. If you'd use the latter, the `foreach` could automatically cast the object to `DataRow`. [`DataRowCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowcollection?view=net-7.0), which is returned from `DataTable.Rows`, is old and does not implement `IEnumerable<DataRow>` but just the non-generic `ICollection`. That's why the `foreach` gets an object.

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt_test.Rows)
{
   // now you can use the methods of DataRow like the indexer
}
```

Apart from that you cannot remove rows from a table in a `foreach` while you are enumerating it. You will get an exception "Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute". But you could fill a remove-list first:

```
List<DataRow> removeList = new();
foreach(DataRow row in dt_test.Rows)
{
   If(condition)
   {
       removeList.Add(row);
   }
}
removeList.ForEach(dt_test.Rows.Remove);
```

Comment: Tim, thank u! Now its works correctly

Answer (score -1):

Row variable resolved as object by compiler when using var. You can see it when you cursor on row. You should determine it not as var, but as DataRow

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).